# identify documents from results of mahout clustering

Tags: solr, mahout

I am using mahout to cluster text documents indexed using solr.

I have used the "text" field in the document to form vectors. Then I used the k-means driver in mahout for clustering and then the clusterdumper utility to dump the results.

I am having difficulty in understanding the output results from the dumper. I could see the clusters formed with term vectors in those clusters. 
But how do I extract the documents from these clusters. I want the result to be the input documents appearing in different clusters.

Comment: I am also looking for an answer to this question.  This discussion:

http://www.lucidimagination.com/search/document/dab8c1f3c3addcfe/validating_clustering_output

seems to imply this is open issue, with a patch implemented in Mahout 0.5 here, issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAHOUT-236.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem. The idea is that cluster dumper dumps all your cluster data with points and so on. You have two choices:

1. modify ClusterDumper.printClusters() method so it will not print all the terms and weights. I have some code like:

```
    String clusterInfo = String.format("Cluster %d (%d) with %d points.\n", value.getId(), clusterCount, value.getNumPoints());
                    writer.write(clusterInfo);
                    writer.write('\n');
    // list all top terms
    if (dictionary != null) {
                        String topTerms = getTopFeatures(value.getCenter(), dictionary, numTopFeatures);
                        writer.write("\tTop Terms: ");
                        writer.write(topTerms);
                        writer.write('\n');
                    }

    // list all the points in the cluster
    List points = clusterIdToPoints.get(value.getId());
                    if (points != null) {
                        writer.write("\tCluster points:\n\t");
                        for (Iterator iterator = points.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                            WeightedVectorWritable point = iterator.next();
                            writer.write(String.valueOf(point.getWeight()));
                            writer.write(": ");

                            if (point.getVector() instanceof NamedVector) {
                                writer.write(((NamedVector) point.getVector()).getName() + " ");
                            }

                        }
                        writer.write('\n');
                    }
```

1. do some grep magic if possible and eliminate all the info about terms and weights.